# can't install citext extension: could not access file "$libdir/citext": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.4, installation, citext

I'm trying to get citext available as a type in a specific database. The Postgres database server is 9.4. I see it on the server in the pg_catalog's pg_available_extensions view.

From the psql console I try to install it and get this error:

```
create extension citext;

ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/citext": No such file or directory
```

Is there a configuration problem? I'm not sure why it would not have the $libdir variable populated.

Answer (score 2):

Did you perhaps install multiple instances of Postgres on the same server? Standard Postgres is not built for that, `$libdir` is compiled into the program. If so, you could fix your problem by uninstalling all other instances and and re-installing your current Postgres version.

Related:

- [Could not access file “$libdir/plpgsql”: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846548/939860)

Comment: Yes, you are on to it. There is a partition for big databases and this database is on that partition while Postgres is not. I still haven;t found the way to fix it yet, however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the contrib modules. They're often not bundled with PostgreSQL.

> postgresql-contrib - additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supported version)

they provide the files it's looking for.

```
postgresql-contrib-9.5: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/citext.so
```